# How to access environment variables during build

Tags: environment-variables, aurelia

How can I access values of environment variables during build in order to do some string replacement.

Example:

**aurelia_project/environments/dev.ts**

```js
export default {
    debug: true,
    testing: true,
    pageBaseUrl: 'https://localhost:9000' // <-- This is the info I'd like to fetch
};
```

**aurelia_project/environments/prod.ts**

```js
export default {
    debug: true,
    testing: true,
    pageBaseUrl: 'https://www.foobar.com' // <-- This is the info I'd like to fetch
};
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- ... -->
    <base href="{pageBasePath}">
    <!-- ... -->
</head>
<!-- ... -->
</html>
```

**aurelia_project/tasks/processIndex.ts**

```js
// ...
export default function processIndex() {
    const pageBasePath = CLI.getEnvParamValue('pageBasePath');

    return gulp.src('index.html')
        .pipe(replace('{pageBasePath}', pageBasePath))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(project.platform.outputIndex));
}
```

Is there some built-in equivalent to my fictional `CLI.getEnvParamValue('pageBasePath');` in `processIndex.ts` or do I have to manually read those infos from the appropriate file inside `aurelia_project/environments` (using `CLIOptions.getEnvironment()`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve this by manually parsing the needed info from the appropriate environment file:

```js
let project = require('../aurelia.json');
import * as replace from 'gulp-replace';
import * as gulp from 'gulp';
import {CLIOptions} from 'aurelia-cli';
import * as fs from 'fs';

export default function processIndex() {
    const env = CLIOptions.getEnvironment();
    const envContent = fs.readFileSync(`aurelia_project/environments/${env}.ts`, 'utf8');
    const pageBaseUrl = /pageBaseUrl: '(.*)'/ig.exec(envContent)[1];

    return gulp.src('index.html')
        .pipe(replace('{pageBaseUrl}', pageBaseUrl))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(project.platform.outputIndex));
}
```

Since this feels quite hacky, I'd still appreciate better alternatives!

Comment: I knew I was screwed importing environment into a gulp build task.  Dude, this saved me...glad you had the code figured out!